# Como imprimir uma lista em Java?

Tags: java

Pessoal eu to estudando a disciplina de POO em Java, eu o professor passou um conteúdo lá que não deu tempo de escrever o código. Aí eu tô com uma baita de uma dúvida!
Eu tenho 3 classes em java. A classe SalaAula, Pessoa e Professor.

SalaAula.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SalaAula {
    private String nomeAluno;
    private int idadeAluno;
    private float pesoAluno;
    private float alturaAluno;
    private int matriculaAluno;

    SalaAula() {

        System.out.println("Seja bem vindo\n\n ");
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        Professor professor = new Professor("Anderson", 32, 1.75f, 110f, 1010220, "Mestre");

        System.out.println("Qual seu nome? ");
        nomeAluno = entrada.next();
        System.out.println("Qual a sua idade? ");
        idadeAluno = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Qual o seu peso? ");
        pesoAluno = entrada.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Qual a sua altura?");
        alturaAluno = entrada.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Qual a sua matrícula?");
        matriculaAluno = entrada.nextInt();

        //Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa(nome, idade, peso, altura, peso, matricula);
        System.out.println(new Professor());
        System.out.println("\n------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Nome:\tIdade:\tPeso:\tAltura:\tMatrícula:");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(nomeAluno + "\t" + idadeAluno + " anos\t" + alturaAluno + "\t" + pesoAluno + "\t" + matriculaAluno);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SalaAula principal = new SalaAula();

    }

}
```

Pessoa.java

```
class Pessoa {
    private int idade;
    private String nome;
    private float altura;
    private float peso;
    private int matricula;

    Pessoa() {

    }

    Pessoa(String nome, int idade, float altura, float peso, int matricula) {
        this.idade = idade;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.altura = altura;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void setAltura(float altura) {
        this.altura = altura;
    }

    public void setPeso(float peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return this.idade;
    }

    public float getAltura() {
        return this.altura;
    }

    public float getPeso() {
        return this.peso;
    }
    public void setMatricula(int matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    public int getMatricula() {
        return this.matricula;
    }
}
```

Professor.java

```
public class Professor extends Pessoa {
    String nivelSuperior;
    Professor() {

    }
    Professor(String nome, int idade, float altura, float peso, int matricula, String nivel) {

        setNome(nome);
        setIdade(idade);
        setAltura(altura);
        setPeso(peso);
        setMatricula(matricula);

        this.nivelSuperior = nivel;
    }
    public String getNivel() {
        return this.nivelSuperior;
    }
    public void setNivel(String nivel) {
        this.nivelSuperior = nivel;
    }
}
```

Aí é o seguinte!
É pra retornar as informações do professor:

```
Professor professor = new Professor("Anderson", 32, 1.75f, 110f, 1010220, "Mestre");
```

E as informações do aluno, que nesse caso vai ser inserida pelo usuário.

Minhas pergunta é: Como que eu faço pra imprimir as informações do professor + informações do aluno?

Tô quebrando a cabeça com isso... Sei que é simples, mas sou noob, então relevem aí kkkkk

Obrigado.

Comment: Mas cade a lista? Não vi arraylist ou array em nenhuma das classes.

Comment: É só o que eu tenho... Por isso eu queria ajuda pra fazer ele retornar esses valores.

Comment: Eu acho que eu coloquei a palavra errada na pergunta....A lista que é pra imprimir é somente:
<pre> Professor professor = new Professor("Anderson", 32, 1.75f, 110f, 1010220, "Mestre");</pre> e as informações de entrada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fazes @override do metodo toString() na classe Professor onde retornarias os atributos deste e depois imprimias. Desta maneira

Classe Professor

```
@override
public String toString(){
    return "Nome:" + nome + " Idade:" + idade+ " Altura:" + altura + " Peso:"+  peso +"Matricula:" + matricula+" Nivel:"+nivel;
```

Classe SalaAula

```
 Professor professor = new Professor("Anderson", 32, 1.75f, 110f, 1010220, "Mestre");
 System.out.println(professor);
```

Comment: Deu certo! Vlw! Eu tinha visto e tinha esquecido de da like, foi mal aí. Mas deu certo mesmo.

Comment: O professor tinha feito: `System.out.println(professor.getNome()+"\t"+professor.getIdade()+"\t"+professor.getPeso()+"\t"+professor.getAltura()+"\t"+professor.getMatricula()+"\t\t"+professor.getNivel());`

Comment: Mas aí ele falou que o meu método é mais rápido.